# Angular 2 and Polymer Web Components - Inconsistent Behavior

Tags: angular, polymer, web-component

Here are four Plnks illustrating four different ways of inserting a [Polymer paper-input](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-input) `<link>` import into an Angular 2 application

**Working**

[paper-input link in a routable component html file](http://plnkr.co/edit/iMLPgxWmc1tfpKC6yZMF?p=preview)

[paper-input link in index.html](http://plnkr.co/edit/jv7OLANldPJcRgqXy93d?p=info)

**Not Working**

[paper-input link in a component template html file](http://plnkr.co/edit/YSrC0PPjO4tcQeXX7YqC?p=preview)

[paper-input link in a component template string](http://plnkr.co/edit/0OKi0idInERODKIJCnCK?p=info)

They are all based on the tour of heroes demo.

The only difference in their polymer integration is the placement of the `<link>` for importing the paper-input.  I was excited to see the two that don't work fail silently :)

The two that don't work appear to load the import of the paper-input in such a way that it is ignored by the browser and then so is the undefined `<paper-input>` tag.

[Enabling full shadow-dom](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/settings) also doesn't seem to make them work.

This seems potentially like a bug with the way Angular 2 is parsing and compiling the various types of templates, but I don't know enough about NG2 parsing to even get started looking at the source.  Any ideas?